# Interpolation and templating

Tags: templating, string-interpolation

I am trying to verify my understanding of string interpolation and string templating.

Is it correct to say that the two Java code snippets are examples of templating?

```
public class Person {
 //showing only relevant code
 public String toString() {
   return "Name: " + name + " salary: " + salary + " address: " + address;
 }
}

public String toString() {
  return String.format("name: %s salary: %d address: %s", name, salary, address);
}
```

This Groovy snippet is an example of string interpolation:

```
public class Person {
  def name
  def salary
  def address

  //showing only relevant parts of the code
  public String toString() {
    return """ name: ${name} salary: ${salary} address: ${address}"""
  }
}
```

Would it be correct to say that Java and Python support templating but no interpolation, but Groovy does support interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

Your first two code snippets are examples of formatting.
Your third snippet is interpolation.

Java's string templating is like interpolation, but more flexible, powerful, and safe.

Java's String Templates feature is described in [JEP 430](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430), and it appears in JDK 21 as a preview feature.  Here is an example use:

```java
return STR."name: \{name} salary: \{salary} address: \{address}"
```